# How do we call a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ made up of intervals and isolated points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, terminology, real-numbers

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with its standard topology. Suppose that $U$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ consisting at most of proper intervals and isolated points.

Is there a standard terminology for $U$?

I would like a term to exclude all other types of subset, which are kind of pathological examples.

Comment: Do you consider (the singleton of) an isolated point an interval of the form $[a,a]$?

Comment: @MarkS. Nope. By "interval" I meant proper interval. I edited the question.

Comment: Standard term?  Probably not, since just about any subset would look like that.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Exactly. I thought there was a standard term to get rid of all "pathological" examples.

Comment: The entire real line consists of single integers and the open intervals between them so it doesn't seem very special.

Comment: @bof Ouch, I was foolish - deleted!

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in *finite* unions of points and intervals, these are called the **”Semi-algebraic”** sets in $\mathbb{R}$. The notion of semi-algebraic extends to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by considering all sets that can be picked out by a finite conjunction of statements of the form $p(x) = 0$ and $q(x) \geq 0$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials in $n$ variables with real coefficients. There is an interesting theorem called the [“Tarski Seidenberg Theorem”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Seidenberg_theorem) that these sets are closed under coordinate projections.

The notion of semi-algebraic set corresponds with the notion of “definable with parameters” from mathematical logic when $\mathbb{R}$ is viewed as a real closed field. The Tarksi Seidenberg Theorem, mentioned above, exactly corresponds to the fact that the theory of real closed fields admits quantifier elimination.

<strike>If you’re interested in infinite unions, then you could say that these are the quantifier-free $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1, \omega}$ definable sets with parameters, but I think that’s more of a mouth full than you’re looking for.</strike>  This is not correct because I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Your last paragraph is incorrect: for example, $\mathbb{Q}$ is quantifier-freely-$\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ definable with parameters.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Maybe I’m miss understanding MK’s question, but isn’t $\mathbb{Q}$ a countable union of singletons?

Comment: *Isolated points*, not singletons. $\mathbb{Q}$ has no isolated points.

Comment: Ahh you are correct. I misunderstood the question.